# Laravel validation

Tags: php, laravel, validação, laravel-5

Eu preciso fazer uma validação de dados vindo de um XML, tem como eu usar um *Validation Request*?

Ou *Validation Request* só serve para dados vindo de um formulário?

Comment: Seria interessante dar um exemplo do XML e o que já tem montado.

Comment: Creio eu que os request servem somente para validações de formulário.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você não pode utilizar diretamente o *Request Validation* do Laravel 5, mas pode utilizar o `Validator` com qualquer *array*. É preciso antes ler o conteúdo do XML.

```
<?php

public function validate(){
    $xml = '<book>
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer\'s Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications with XML.</description>
    </book>';

    // Rotina para extrair os dados do XML
    $xmlData = (array) simplexml_load_string($xml);

    $rules = [
        'author' => 'string|required',
        'title' => 'string|required',
        'genre' => 'string',
        'price' => 'numeric',
        'publish_date' => 'date',
        'description' => 'string'
    ];

    if (Validator::make($xmlData, $rules)){
        return $xmlData;
    }

    return 'XML Invalido :(';

}
```